# e2e Angular 2 with protractor, element(by.id('count')).getText() showing null

Tags: angular, protractor, integration-testing, e2e-testing

My test run is getting failed by showing the message
**- Expected '' to equal 101**. What may be the issue with this code,In the UI I am getting proper result .The div with the id `SequenceMasterCount` is hidden while loading the page, after the click on the search button the div starts showing with the content of the api result.

```
import { CleanUiPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';    
describe('clean-ui App', () => {
  let page: CleanUiPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new CleanUiPage();
  });    

  it('should allow searching and Show the count', () => {

    const searchButton = element(by.className('list-ro-input'));
    const searchBox = element(by.className('list-RO-search'));
    searchBox.sendKeys('[PIMS]SYSTEM+GAP_FILL_TEST');
    searchButton.click().then(() => {    
      expect(element(by.id('SequenceMasterCount')).getText()).toEqual(101);

    });

  });
```

Added the HTML from comments by OP

```
 <section>  
 <input id="list-ro" class="list-ro-input" name="" type="text" #test /> 
 <span class="input-group-btn"> <a href="javascript: void(0);" id='list-ro-search-btn' class="list-RO-search btn btn-default" (click)=onSearch(test)></a> </span> 
  <div [hidden]="this.sequencemasters==0 && this.sequencemasterAlts==0"> 
  <div class="sequenceCount"> 
  <span class="cat__core__step__title">Sequence Master</span> <p id='sequenceMasterCount' class="count-bold">{{this.sequencemasters}}</p> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getText()` method should be resolving a promise, since `getText()` returns a promise that needs to be resolved

you need to add this

```
   searchButton.click().then(() => {    
   element(by.id('SequenceMasterCount'))getText().then(function(text){
       expect(text).toEqual(101);        
        });

});
```

Comment: @peter i tried that way also  but still same result searchButton.click().then(() => {
      expect(element(by.id('sequenceMasterCount')).getText().then(
        function (text) {
          expect(text).toEqual(101);
        }
      ));
    });

Comment: please share the HTML snippet.

Comment: `<section>
    <input id="list-ro" class="list-ro-input" name="" type="text"  #test  />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" id='list-ro-search-btn'  class="list-RO-search btn btn-default" (click)=onSearch(test)></a>
    </span>
    <div [hidden]="this.sequencemasters==0 && this.sequencemasterAlts==0">
        <div class="sequenceCount">
            <span class="cat__core__step__title">Sequence Master</span>
            <p id='sequenceMasterCount' class="count-bold">{{this.sequencemasters}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>` @peter

Comment: I don't see the text that you're trying to assert anywhere. If you're trying to assert `{{this.sequencemasters}}`, then add the HTML, once this field is populated, so that one can see what the DOM looks like once the field is populated.

Comment: this.sequencemasters is given to hide the div by default,When the click works its will get the value true and will show the div

Comment: issue is with the onSearch(res) {
    this.selectedMagescenarios = res.value;
 const allMageInvoiceSubscription = this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
      query: allMageinvoicesequencemasters,
      variables: {
        scenariokey: selectedMagescenarios,
      },
    }); 
    allMageInvoiceSubscription.refetch().then(allData => {
        this.sequencemasters = allData['data']['allMageinvoicesequencemasters']['totalCount'];
    });
  }